# How to place a System.Drawing.Graphics object in browser window

Tags: c#, asp.net, graphics, mono

I'd like to understand how to use C# for drawing an image in my browser window - alongside other HTML objects that are already there. (Idea: To place buttons and forms that allow the user to alter the image.) 
I am doing this in Mono on Linux, but I'd like the thing to be portable. 
What I came up with so far is:

```
public virtual void button1Clicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        int height = 300;
        int width = 300;

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        //
        //Draw something on g here
          //
        Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
        bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
        g.Dispose();
        bmp.Dispose;

    }
```

This clears the browser window and then displays the image, which is not what I wanted. 
After extensive search I found the following tutorial,
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/67275-the-wonders-of-systemdrawinggraphics/
which says I should try to use a Handle on some control in my window, alternatively the CreateGraphics() method. Neither of these seem to exist for my "button1" or any other id of an entity in my .aspx page. Is that because I'm using Mono?

To sum up, what is the best way to draw inside a browser window in C# + asp.net??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same thing to do some time ago,
the thing is that you will have to save your graphic object/bitmap to a location if you want to use it in an iFrame or Image control.

If you don't want to save it to a location,
try using a server script on your page : 
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/2569/creating-images-on-the-fly-with-aspnet/

Comment: Thanks - but as far as I can see, the link you provided describes a method identical to mine but in a script instead of c#!
Am I using the wrong tools for creating graphics-on-the-fly? Tried javascript + SVG before; problem with that is that very few browsers have included correctly all features of SVG.

Comment: well actualy the script has a runat server attribute which gives you the possibility to put C# code inside, and i wondered if the place where your script is could draw the image at the same place.

Comment: Thanks :) .. after all I used the roundabout way of drawing to an image and loading that. Served my purposes well! I guess I could make the other way work - saving that for later.

Comment: you're welcome,i also found another way: use a Http Handler and and use it's Url for the Image "src" attribute